# How to enter sudo password from command line?

Tags: shell

I want to enter sudo password from command line .

but i am facing problem in the script .

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh -tt server_name<<'EOSSH'
sudo su - user
cd /move-to-path/
echo "done"
EOSSH
exit
```

Comment: What did you try ? What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: wouldn't running the file as sudo solve the problem? "Saving" passwords in cleartext is considered a bad practice ...

Comment: @roshith@pythoes.. I tried other way to but its not working .getting below error.is not allowed to execute '/bin/su - sps echo ' as root

Comment: The error message says that you can't run "/bin/su" as root. Check your sudoer setting , /etc/sudoers , you might have permission to run "/usr/bin/su" or "/sbin/su" but not "/bin/su". Change your script accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

export password as environment variable

```
export PASS=yourpassword

echo $PASS
```

now you can use it in script like:

```
echo $PASS | sudo -S su
echo $PASS | sudo -S apt-get install update
```

the password will be passed to sudo su command via -S flag